# ¿como aumentar en uno y restar en uno dentro de un input?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un input con un botón en cada extremo uno con signo de mas y otro con signo de menos quiero aumentar en uno cuando pulse el signo mas y disminuir en uno cuando presione el signo menos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te han comentado deberías de formular correctamente la pregunta, aún así te adjunto un código que puede ayudarte:

```js
function incrementer(){
    var i = document.getElementById("counter");
    i.value++;
}

function decrementer(){
    var i = document.getElementById("counter");
    i.value--;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h2>Contador</h2>
<form action="">
  <p>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="counter" value="0" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Incrementer" id="btnIncrement" onclick="incrementer()">
    <input type="button" value="Decrementer" id="btnDecrement" onclick="decrementer()">
  </p>
</form>
</center>
```

El código básicamente crea un input no editable(para que no puedas sobre escribirlo) que muestra un 0 como valor inicial.
Después tenemos dos botones uno que incrementa y otro que decrementa. Cada uno de ellos llama a su método correspondiente.Los métodos decrementer e incrementer son parecidos, se encargan de recoger el valor del input y sumarle o restarle uno, y este cambio se ve reflejado en el input.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.